# "Invalid Label" with jquery and jsonp (cross-domain)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, client, jsonp

I'm trying to get data from a remote server using jsonp and i'm having some problems.
first i had problems with the authentication issue but (i think) it's ok now. Anyways, i'm getting an "Invalid Label" Error on firebug when trying out my code which looks like that:

```
$(function() {
var url = 'http://lifeloopdev.info/get_events?callback=?';
    $.ajax(url, {  
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: "offset=0&num_items=10",
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        jsonp: 'successCallback'
    });  
});  

function successCallback(data) {  
    $.each(data.success, function(i,item){
        $("body").append('<h1>' + item.title + '</h1>');
    });
};
```

I've also tried it without the success function (instead of jsonp: 'successCallback'):

```
success: function(data) {  
        successCallback(data);
    }
```

my json file:

```
{"success":[{"id":1,"title":"title 1"},{"id":2,"title":"title 2"},{"id":3,"title":"title 3"}]}
```

It seems that the ajax function gets the data but having difficulties parsing it or something like that.

I'll be more then happy if you can help me with this, i spent the last 4 hours trying to figure it out with no success. Thank you very much for your time helping me.

Aviram.

Answer (score 10):

I missed some stuff at first glance - where you've specified your JSON file, I thought you said your JSON response. The root of your problem is that the response *must* be of the form `callbackFunctionName(jsonData)`. If it's not padded that way, you will get the `invalid label` error in Firebug since jQuery will try to interpret the response as a call to a function but there won't be any function name in the response.

Your usage of `$.ajax()` for the JSONP callback function is slightly incorrect right now and that's causing this issue. The value assigned to `jsonp` indicates the *name of the query string parameter* - this should match the parameter name that the server is expecting. In your case, it looks like the server is expecting the parameter name `callback` and not `successCallback`. It is not the string that will be used in the padded JSON recieved. `jsonpCallback` can specify the name of this function - that should be assigned the value of `successCallback`, if you'd like to use a named function and not the `success` function.

---

Assuming the server is expecting the callback function name in the query parameter named `callback`, your code should be one of the following:

1. By default jQuery will add `callback=?` when you don't specify a `jsonp` variable. Note the use of the `success` callback function in this code snippet. :

   ```
   $(function() {
       var url = 'http://lifeloopdev.info/get_events';
       $.ajax(url, {  
           dataType: "jsonp",
           data: "offset=0&num_items=10",
           username: 'username',
           password: 'password',
           success: function(data){
               $.each(data.success, function(i,item){
                   $("body").append('<h1>' + item.title + '</h1>');
               });
           }
       });  
   });
   ```

   The URL that jQuery will attempt to GET will be `http://lifeloopdev.info/get_events?offset=0&num_items=10&callback=jQuery152035532653917078266_4305276802416`. Note that the string `callback` is a query string parameter name and it's value has been autogenerated by jQuery - this will finally invoke your `success` function.

   The response should look like `jQuery152035532653917078266_4305276802416({"success":[{"id":1,"title":"title 1"},{"id":2,"title":"title 2"},{"id":3,"title":"title 3"}]})`
2. If you'd like to use a custom callback function name, see the code below:

   ```
   $(function() {
       var url = 'http://lifeloopdev.info/get_events';
       $.ajax(url, {  
           dataType: "jsonp",
           data: "offset=0&num_items=10",
           username: 'username',
           password: 'password',
           jsonpCallback: 'successCallback'
       });  
   });  

   function successCallback(data) {  
       $.each(data.success, function(i,item){
           $("body").append('<h1>' + item.title + '</h1>');
       });
   };
   ```

   In this case, the URL that jQuery will attempt to GET will be `http://lifeloopdev.info/get_events?offset=0&num_items=10&callback=successCallback`. A proper response will cause the function named `successCallback` to be invoked.

   In this case, the response should look like `successCallback({"success":[{"id":1,"title":"title 1"},{"id":2,"title":"title 2"},{"id":3,"title":"title 3"}]})`

If your callback function query string parameter is *not* to be named `callback` but is something like `cbfunc` instead, you will need to add `jsonp : 'cbfunc'` to your `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: +1 - yeah we pretty much said the same thing. Your's looks more complete now though. ;-)

Comment: OK, i understand. But that means that i have to change the success function syntax? if the response is now "successCallback({"success":[{..." i still have to do "$.each(data.success..."? because i get the same error. thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @Aviram You shouldn't be getting that error if your JSONP is correctly formed - can you post the actual response? You should be able to see it in Firebug's Net panel. And no, if your JSON is as you've posted, you won't need to change anything since the role of JSONP here is to allow your callback function to be invoked after a cross-domain request - the data being passed is still the same.

Answer (score 3):

Are you actually padding your json response serverside to turn into jsonp? i.e. instead of json like:

```
{"success":[{"id":1,"title":"title 1"},{"id":2,"title":"title 2"},{"id":3,"title":"title 3"}]}
```

you should be returning

```
callback({"success":[{"id":1,"title":"title 1"},{"id":2,"title":"title 2"},{"id":3,"title":"title 3"}]});
```

where "callback" is the value of the callback query string parameter passed to the server. Jquery automatically generates this unless you supply the jsonpCallback setting.

I also don't think you need to put the "?callback=?" in your URL, as I believe jquery adds this automatically.

Plus, jsonp: successCallback is telling Jquery to replace ?callback=? with successCallback - But I don't think this is what you're actually intending here. You probably DO want to use "success: function(data)..."

It may be worth having a careful read of the jquery documents on [ajax and jsonp](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: +1 I see that after I came back and updated my answer, I've said essentially the same thing with regards to the jQuery code!